# Does reading the Cosmos DB Change Feed consume RU/s?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Does reading the Cosmos DB Change Feed consume RU/s on the container whose feed is being read? From my experimentation, I think the answer is "no", but I'd love confirmation. I cannot find the answer in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charge for Change Feed is essentially the same as Read Feed. Reading the Change Feed (with no results) consumes 2 RU/s. With results, as Read Feed, it depends on the number and volume of those results.

Comment: Interesting, is there any doc related to it?

Comment: Fair question, I don't believe this is documented anywhere. I'll ask if the owners can add this information.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I am struggling with a similar question, also can't find any concrete doc (just as @Sajeetharan) but my findings may be of help to you. I was wondering how listening to the Change Feed would affect the registered traffic (or better: RU count). I expected it to be of minimal impact and in any case **much** lower than a manual polling mechanism. That should be a major point of a Change Feed, shouldn't it?

**Remark:** I am using C# and the **CosmosDB-MongoDB-API**. So the experienced behaviour might be an effect of the API implementation and not a result of the CosmosDB bookkeeping.

Anyway, I noticed this in my Metrics page:
[image: ~300 requests per 5min]

This was a test with a C# application just running a `Watch()` on a collection, printing a marker as soon as the watcher noticed a change. Basically this:

```
using (var cursor = c.Watch(pipeline, new ChangeStreamOptions
        {
            FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup,
        }))
        {
            foreach (var change in cursor.ToEnumerable())
            {
                // process change event
                Console.WriteLine(change);
            }
        }
```

With no changes to the collection, something obviously caused costs of about **1 RU/s**... In my case, I don't need immediate notifications, so manual polling every few seconds would be much cheaper. That seems to narrow the purpose of the Change Feed a lot.

After reading the answer of @MatiasQuaranta (especially noticing the difference of 2RU/s vs. 1RU/s), I wanted to provide this piece of information as well. I still hope someone will come up with a more documented answer.